# Is it mandotory for client application to register with Azure AD to access Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am creating a application which can communicate with Ms Graph Api to access Office36 mails. For that do i need to mandatorily register my application with AZURE portal

Comment: why i am getting downvote for this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Reference with the below links it is mandatory to Register with Azure AD to access Microsoft Graph Api.

[Ms Grpah Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0